# how can i run an android mobile application with Genymotion from eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I downloaded a source code of an android mobile application and I installed Genymotion and I configured it on eclipse but when I open the project of my application on eclipce, the moment when I click on the button "run" for the test, it Does not work on the virtual phone. I can't even find the application icon on the Genymotion virtual phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to Add genymotion plugin and also have to give path of the folder where genymotion in Installed.